# Point arrow in vector direction

Tags: vector, processing

I'm trying to point an arrow in the direction of a vector (which in this casse is a wind), but am utterly lost.

This is what I've done so far:

```
PVector wind = new PVector(0.01, 0.00);
float degrees = atan(wind.y / wind.x);
rotate(radians(degrees));
// draw an upwards pointing arrow
```

I'm no genius with maths; not even sure about if the degrees are right, but it's the only formula I can find on the internet.

Comment: You have two options: do the rotation and then draw the arrow, or use basic trig (cos and sin) to figure out where the lines of the arrow should be. I suggest you just try one of those methods and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured something (with help from this thread, https://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1219607845.html).

```
noStroke();
fill(0);
rotate(atan2(location.x, location.y));
ellipse(location.x, location.y, 10, 10);
triangle(location.x - -5, location.y + 0, location.x - 5, location.y + 0, location.x - 0, location.y - 10);
```